# Exit app on double tap (android app)

Tags: c#, android, back-button

Am totally stuck here with the following code.

Where do I need to paste this code exactly in c# script in unity...

Because am confused that we have to write

```
using unityengine;
using system.collections,
```

bla blaa so what is the code goes before override

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) 
        super.onBackPressed();
    else 
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press once again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's C# there? Android is probably Java, and I'm pretty sure that's which language has _@Override_ as a keyword. _andriod_ may use a different language altogether, however.

Comment: So thanks ceisc then i try to update tihis code in java and let u know

Comment: Ceisc can you help me this .......how can i exit my application on double tab for android .......am using unity3d

Comment: @NickyShankar the code you have posted here is Java code and not c#, it will work in native app and not game made using unity3d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in c#

```
void Update(){
   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) 
    Application.Quit(); 
 }
```

or in .js

```
function Update(){
   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)) 
    Application.Quit(); 
 }
```

This is the function for exit app when back button pressed, if you want to exit the app when back button pressed twice, implement the logic in the java code you have posted in question into equivalent code in unity i.e initialise a variable to store current time in millis on first back button press and show message to press once again to exit, and if next back button press is within two seconds of first press, then exit app.

If you want this to work on a button click etc, implement the same technique and call `Application.Quit()` instead of `super.onBackPressed()` in java.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this code, but my application doesn't quit. Are you sure that this way is useful for exit? My code is : `using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class customEventHandler : MonoBehaviour {

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
 }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
  if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
  {
   Application.Quit();
   // or ask to quit
  }

  if (Input.GetKey ("escape")) {
   Application.Quit();
  }
 }

}
`

Answer (score 0):

**Exit app on double tap ( android unity)
**

```
public bool quitBool = false;

void Update()
{
        if(Input.touchCount > 1)quitBool = false;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape) && quitBool == true){
            Application.Quit();
        }
        if(Input.anyKey){
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))quitBool = true;
            else quitBool = false;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement like below to quite the app in twist Escape button click within 3 seconds

```
 private bool _IsEscape = false; // private field


    void Update(){
         if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.ESCAPE)){
             if (_IsEscape)
                    {                        
                        Application.Quit();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _IsEscape = true;                        
                        if (!IsInvoking("DisableDoubleClick"))
                            Invoke("DisableDoubleClick", 0.3f);


                    }
                }
         }

     }

     void DisableDoubleClick(){
         _IsEscape = false;
     }
```